# Sobolev space $W^{1,2} (\Omega)$ is an Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis

If I consider  $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ with the norm $||f||_{W^{1,2}}=(||f||^2_{L^2}+||f'||^2_{L^2})^{1\over2}$ is an Hilbert space because is true the parallelogram law?

$f'$ is the weak derivatives of $f$

$||f||_{W^{1,2}}=(\int_{\Omega}|f|^2 dx +\int_{\Omega} |f'|^2 dx)^{1 \over 2}$

and the inner product : $<f,g>=\int_{\Omega}fg dx +\int_{\Omega}f'g' dx$

I want prove $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is complete with the norm $||.||_{W^{1,2}}$.

I consider a Cauchy-sequence $\{f_n\}$ in ${W^{1,2}}$. Because $||f'_n-f'_m||^2_{L^2}\le||f_n-f_m||_{W^{1,2}}$ then $\{f'_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\Omega)$.$\quad$
$L^2$ is a complete space so exists $g\in L^2: ||f'_n-g||_{L^2} \rightarrow0$

But how can I complete the proof?

Let $\Omega=(a,b )$.$\quad |f_n(a)-f_m(a)| \le ||f_n-f_m||_{W^{1,2}}$ so $\{f_n(a)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and $\alpha = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(a)$. If I define $f(t)=\alpha+\int_{a}^{t} g(s) ds $ then $f\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

It's right?

Comment: Yes. Whenever the parallelogram law holds in a normed space, it induces an inner product by polarization. In a Banach space this induces a Hilbert space structure.

Comment: It's the norm in $L^2$

Comment: @Dayton I think it is clear from context that $g = f'$, and the question is why $H^1$ is a Hilbert space knowing that $W^{1,2}$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 0):

So you know that $f_n'$ and $f_n$ have limits in $L^2$, is there a connection between those limits ?

Comment: $W^{1,2}(\Omega)=\{\alpha+\int_{0}^{t} g(s)ds: \alpha \in R, g \in L^2(\Omega)\}$

Comment: How can I finish the proof?